# How to unblock port 1521 for Oracle on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: connection, oracle

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and Oracle 10XE. I logged in to the Oracle and did `startup`. Everything is connected, Oracle has been started.

Then I saw the following error:

```
telnet localhost 1521 Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I would like to use Oracle with default port and I need to unblock it to use my Java application.

Could you give me a simple solution, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

iptables is the underlying database for Ubuntu firewalls, so in ipdates we need to remove any blocks for port 1521 for that machine.

iptables lives in RAM, so you need to dump the existing data out to a file, a la:

`sudo iptables-save > /some/directory/your_rules.fw`

and during the booting process make sure iptables reads that file with

`sudo iptables-restor < /some/directory/your_rules.fw`

and you need to open up that port with a command like

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT`
`sudo iptables -l`

as well as checking in your router or gateway to make sure it's not blocking port 1521, either.

A tutorial is available at https://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configuring_IPtables_on_ubuntu_server

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer. I am a beginner, could you tell me, how I can do that ?

Comment: I did: 1. sudo iptables-save > /home/aleksander/Documents/oracleportconfig/my_rules.fw 2. sudo iptables-restore < /home/aleksander/Documents/oracleportconfig/my_rules.fw 3. sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT 4. sudo iptables -l but "-l" is unknown option. After that I restarted ORACLE and did telnet again with the same error. How I can check, on which port ORACLE works ?

Comment: **sudo iptables -L**
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1521
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1521

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination